# Named Address Spaces for MSVC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, x86, cpu-registers

GCC and Clang support a feature called [Named Address Space](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html), that allows users to instruct the compiler to generate accesses to certain variables or members through `FS` or `GS` register.

Does MSVC support a feature like this?

(I have not been able to find anything on MSDN, but seeing how Windows has long allowed users to change the value of segment registers with `FSGSBASE`, the compiler must be providing some way to actually arrange the data appropriately, right?)

Comment: Aren't fs and gs already used for tls on x86?

Comment: I guess you need [some assembly](https://gist.github.com/MerryMage/f22e75d5128c07d77630ca01c4272937)

Comment: @phuclv That link only seem to contains info on how to set the registers, but not how to coax the compiler in generating code which accesses some variables through offsetting by FS or GS.

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC most low-level things are done via intrinsics. Same to this

- Read the base address: [`_readfsbase_u32`, `_readgsbase_u32`, `_readfsbase_u64`,`_readgsbase_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_readfsbase)
- Write the base address: [`_writefsbase_u32`, `_writegsbase_u32`, `_writefsbase_u64`, `_writegsbase_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_writefsbase)

See [x64 (amd64) intrinsics list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list?view=msvc-160)

To operate on the pointer relative to the base address use

- [`__addfsbyte`, `__addfsword`, `__addfsdword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addfsbyte-addfsword-addfsdword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__addgsbyte`, `__addgsword`, `__addgsdword`, `__addgsqword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addgsbyte-addgsword-addgsdword-addgsqword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__incfsbyte`, `__incfsword`, `__incfsdword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/incfsbyte-incfsword-incfsdword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__incgsbyte`, `__incgsword`, `__incgsdword`, `__incgsqword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/incgsbyte-incgsword-incgsdword-incgsqword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__readfsbyte`, `__readfsdword`, `__readfsqword`, `__readfsword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readfsbyte-readfsdword-readfsqword-readfsword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__readgsbyte`, `__readgsdword`, `__readgsqword`, `__readgsword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readgsbyte-readgsdword-readgsqword-readgsword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__writefsbyte`, `__writefsdword`, `__writefsqword`, `__writefsword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/writefsbyte-writefsdword-writefsqword-writefsword?view=msvc-160)
- [`__writegsbyte`, `__writegsdword`, `__writegsqword`, `__writegsword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/writegsbyte-writegsdword-writegsqword-writegsword?view=msvc-160%27)

Here's an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int data[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    
    std::cout << "&data = " << (void*)&data << '\n';
    std::cout << "GS base before                    = " << (void*)_readgsbase_u64() << '\n';

    _writegsbase_u64((uintptr_t)&data);
    std::cout << "GS base after pointing to data[0] = " << (void*)_readgsbase_u64() << '\n';

    std::cout << "GS:[1] = " << __readgsdword(1) << ", GS:[3] = " << __readgsdword(3) << '\n';

    _writegsbase_u64((uintptr_t)&data[7]);
    std::cout << "GS base after pointing to data[7] = " << (void*)_readgsbase_u64() << '\n';

    std::cout << "GS:[0] = " << __readgsdword(0) << ", GS:[2] = " << __readgsdword(2) << '\n';
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know why in intrin.h the GS functions are only available in 64-bit mode and FS functions are only available in 32-bit mode. Since GS is used for TLS in 64-bit Windows I couldn't change it. Calling `_writegsbase_u64` seems to do nothing when I step over the program, the base address is still the same before and after setting. So currently the above code doesn't work on my machine

Comment: Note that `rdgsbase` and related instructions are *not* baseline for x86-64 (new in IvyBridge with the FSGSBASE feature), and the kernel has to enable their use with a bit in CR4, else #UD.  They're also not recognized in protected/compat mode, according to Intel's manual https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdfsbase:rdgsbase (only 64-bit mode), so that's weird for MSVC to have intrinsics in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Or did you mean `__readfsdword` / `__addfsdword` etc. to generate instructions with addressing modes like `fs:[ ... ]` were only available in 32-bit mode (*using* the FS base), not that `_readfsbase_u32` (to *read* the FS base) was available?

Comment: *Calling _writegsbase_u64 seems to do nothing when I step over the program* - What do you mean by "nothing"?  Does this example not actually work?  https://godbolt.org/z/Y5dxanoKq shows it compiles to things like `lea  rax,  data$[rsp]`
/ `wrgsbase rax`

Comment: @PeterCordes I mean the GS base doesn't change when calling `_writegsbase_u64`. The GS base before and after setting are the same. The `_readfsbase` is only available in 64-bit mode as defined in `immintrin.h`, but the dereference intrinsics are only defined in one mode, like `__writefsword` in 32-bit and `__writegsword` in 64-bit mode

Comment: @PeterCordes but why do we need to read 32-bit base address in 64-bit mode when pointers are 64-bit long?

Comment: The instruction is available in both operand-sizes, and apparently Intel chose to define intrinsics for both sizes.  (Note that Intel's asm manual documents those intrinsics, they weren't MS's idea.  So the use-cases include ILP32-in-long-mode ABIs like Linux x32, and cases where you use MMAP_32BIT for the pointer you used in wrfsbase.  Not just Windows.  Of course a smart compiler could just see you were assigning the result to a 32-bit type and omit the REX.W prefix, so you'd only need one intrinsic, but Intel chose not to do that.)

Comment: When you say the GS base doesn't change, do you mean the `_readgsbase_u64()` result doesn't change, but you get the desired array values?  Or do you *also* mean your example doesn't work, instead printing ints from the Windows [Thread Information Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) for `__readgsdword(0)`?

Comment: Oh, you said when you single-step.  That might mean the kernel or the debugger is setting GSBASE to what it's "supposed" to be for thread-local storage any time you enter the kernel.  (Via the MSR, or via `wrgsbase` in the kernel.)  But if you run these instructions in user-space without stopping, you get the results added to the cout I/O buffer before making a system call and resetting GSBASE.  So it's plausible that Windows doesn't support setting custom GS bases in user-space code.  (And they're Intel intrinsics, not MSVC, and of course are useful in kernel code on CPUs that support them.)

Comment: Just saw your update clarifying the example didn't work.  It might when redirected to a file, if that gets `cout >>` to avoid flushing on newlines, if it's the kernel destroying your GSBASE!  (Or try saving results to variables, and only printing after capturing both the rdgsbase and the `gsdword(0)` result.)

Comment: @PeterCordes possibly that the kernel restores the GSBASE because if I run the executable directly it'll cause a segfault. Maybe I don't have the correct Windows SDK or I need to enable some flags to do that

Comment: An SDK should just be header files.  You can verify that the right instructions are inlined into your function with a disassembler or debugger.  A segfault is surprising; if Windows didn't enable `CR4.FSGSBASE[bit 16] = 0`, the manual says you'd get `#UD` (illegal instruction) on `rdgsbase`, not #GP or similar exception like you would from trying to run a privileged instruction.  And a `#PF` on the `gs:[abs 0]` shouldn't happen if GSBASE is actually set correctly, since you already touched that stack memory to init the array.  Or if GSBASE is unmodified, the TIB should be readable, I think?

Comment: Just for the record, on x86-64 Linux 5.9 on a Skylake CPU, I commented out the `__readgsdword` stuff so I could compile it with `g++`.  The `GS base before = 0` / `GS base after pointing to data[0] = 0x7ffdb9dd6b00` prints fine, and matches the `&data` address.  And with inline asm instead of `__readgsdword(1)` and 3, I was able to read from the array.  https://godbolt.org/z/fGTbos8sc works for me locally, but not on Godbolt.  SIGILL on rdgsbase = exit status 128+4 = 132.  And yes I used GS on GNU/Linux, even though TLS uses FS.  The kernel's swapgs apparently doesn't mess up the GS BASE.